# Facebook API for custom feelings/activity

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I was searching in the Facebook API documentation, but I can't find what I am looking for. So, what I am looking for is is there an API for creating your custom DO action. For example:

> John Johson is **riding** a **bike**.

What I want is to send this '**riding**' as a custom word coming from my app. And also '**bike**' as a custom item as well.
The other example I can think about is the running apps in Facebook. When you start to run and connect the app with your Facebook the app can say.

> John Johson is **running** using **Runtastic**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you’re a little too late on that one.

That used to be possible, it was called Custom Open Graph Actions - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom

But those are now deprecated, you can not use them any more in new apps (and for existing ones, they will be removed within a year as well), see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom-open-graph-deprecation

Now you can only use the built-in actions and objects, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph