# Facebook graph API android add feelings in post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook android SDK (V4) to post a message on Facebook using  "me/feed" graph API.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", message);

new GraphRequest(
    token,
    "me/feed",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            //Handle response
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

This is working fine.
Now I want to add feeling/Activity in my post.
I have search on Google but haven't found any solution on that.
Does anybody know of a way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355126/facebook-api-for-custom-feelings-activity

Comment: @Meenal that’s not the same issue. The “... feeling {foo}” info you can add to your posts via the UI has nothing to do with Open Graph actions.

Comment: There is no parameter to set this when posting via API.

Comment: @Meenal I checked that link but not found any parameter to add in graph API.